# how do I restart the support tool process for VMWare Player in Windows?

Tags: vmware-player

I'm having trouble getting copy from Windows and paste to Ubuntu (guest) working correctly or consistently. I can copy from guest to host fine, but not the other way, at least not consistently. It works, but then 10 minutes later it won't work. Then later it will work again. I've asked on VMWare's site and gotten no help (typical forums, loads of similar questions that were never really answered).

Is there a Windows process that I can restart? The only thing I see is vmware-unity-helper, but I wasn't able to restart that. I can get copy paste to work better by restarting the VM, but that seems a bit much, hoping for a shorter way.

Comment: I have the same issue. Fresh vmware player on ubuntu 14.04 and modern.ie Windows 7 image. Did you ever figure out what was the cause?